# i have a vba code to return multiple matches in a single cell, however it takes longtime to execute. Any way to speedup the macro

Tags: excel, vba

```
Option Explicit

Function VLOOKUP1(lookupval, lookuprange As Range, indexcol As Long)

Dim r As Range    
Dim result As String

result = vbNullString

For Each r In lookuprange

    If r = lookupval Then

        result = result & " , " & r.Offset(0, indexcol - 1)

    End If

Next r

VLOOKUP1 = result 

End Function
```

Comment: indexcol does not change within the function so remove it from the loop and do the calculation before the For Each then just use the calculated variable in the loop.

Comment: What size is the range `lookuprange` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams - MIS data (database) has around 70000 rows and 50 columns and approx 35000 values (main sheet) for which search is to be carried out on database and result to be updated in the main sheet

Comment: Was the code I posted faster?  With that much data you might be better off using a sub to perform the matching, maybe using some kind of dictionary lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you read a range costs you performance, so you need to minimise how many times you do that.  One way is to first read the data into arrays, and work with those instead.

```vba
Option Explicit

Function VLOOKUP1(lookupval, lookuprange As Range, indexcol As Long)
    Dim r As Long, arr, arr2, sep As String, result As String
    
    arr = lookuprange.Value   'read ranges to arrays
    arr2 = lookuprange.Offset(0, indexcol - 1).Value
    'loop the lookup column values
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        If arr(r, 1) = lookupval Then
            result = result & sep & arr2(r, 1)
            sep = ", " 'add separator after first value
        End If
    Next r
    VLOOKUP1 = result
End Function
```